# A shortcut in the Delphi IDE triggers two actions

Tags: delphi, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

Maybe this question is very specific for me, but I'll give it a try. Here's the scenario:

1. In Delphi XE2 the shortcut "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>" toggles bookmark  (likewise <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[1..9]</kbd> for the other bookmarks)
2. I have installed ModelMaker Tools (v. 9.1.0, but I believe I had this error earlier also), where I have assigned the shortcut "<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>" to "Sync Declaration/Implementation".

Whenever I use the ModelMaker shortcut I also set the bookmark (7). Why is this? Note that contrary to the "real" shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>) the bookmark isn't toggled, only set.

This behaviour puzzles me. Does anyone have an explanation? It's not a big problem, since I rarely use that many bookmarks, but it got me curious.

Comment: I have seen some weird bugs in the IDE where keyboard shortcuts seem cross-wired, but never this particular thing. Try changing the keyboard shortcut assignment for the MM Tools and see if it goes away.

Comment: It's not a bug it's a feature. Yes, it really is an MMX feature, not a Delphi bug (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a couple of refactorings, ModelMaker Code Explorer sets some bookmarks for your convenience.

It is documented somewhere<strike>, but I forgot where (:</strike>

**Edit**: it is documented [here](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/history/mmx315.html).

> All refactoring operations that modify the IDE edit buffers
>   (optionally) drop bookmark #7 at the current cursor position. Similar
>   to how Extract Method drops bookmarks #8 at the original code and #9
>   at the extracted method. The bookmark numbers can be customized on the
>   History Tab which also allows disabling dropping specific bookmarks.

Comment: I was starting to believe I had discovered a bug, but clearly I hadn't. Thanks :-)